# Words for numbers in a language with bijective numeration

Tags: conlang-creation, vocabulary, syntax, number

[Bijective base-*k* numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) (or *k*-adic numeration) is a system of writing numerals such that the digits are 1 through *k*. Thus counting in bijective base-12 (such as my conlang Atili has) works as follows, using `X`, `E`, and `T` for ten, eleven, and twelve, respectively:

```
 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  X,  E,  T,
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 1X, 1E, 1T,
21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 2X, 2E, 2T,
...
```

What are reasonable ways to assign names to these numbers, specifically combining tens? Obviously, I could just name the numbers the way English does and just have the names for numbers not line up with how they are written (so "a dozen" would be `T`, but "a dozen and one" `11`), but are there other solutions for naming that better align with the way that numbers are written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just have two different words, like "twelve" (T) and "dozen". Than the number 1T is one-dozen-and-twelve.

Comment: Well, that was pretty obvious. I feel kinda silly now.

Comment: Well. it is only obvious when one's native language already has the two words "twelve" and "dozen" available. Thinking of bijective base-16, there are no such obvious words available.

Answer (score 4):

The solution I've gone with is to use two different words as jk suggests in [his answer](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/a/1222/2609). In speech, both "one-dozen and twelve" (*"rurinye-tendi"*) and "two dozen" (*"barinye"*) are acceptable, but have slightly different meanings. *Rurinye-tendi* means exactly 24, while *barinye* means at least 24, but not more than 36. The latter is frequently used for approximations and estimations. In writing, *rurinye-tendi* can be either written as 1T or fully spelled-out, but *barinye* must be spelled out because there is no way to write it with numerals.

Answer (score 3):

1. if the base system is deeply ingrained in the language (in most (all?) natlangs it isn't, numbers predate modern positional notation by millennia; let's say your language had the notation for a long long time and historical language changes made the language conform to the notation), then the most natural system is just to read the digits - T is *dozen*, 11 is *one-one*.
2. or make the base multiplier obligatory for numbers bigger than the base - T is *dozen* but 11 is *one dozen (and) one*